# Can't do anything on HD NTFS partition, my user is the owner

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, permissions, ntfs-3g

Here's the thing. I used to have an Asus computer with Ubuntu and Windows 7 on dual boot since 2014. I used to update Ubuntu everytime a new version was released, and I updated to Windows 10 too. Both shared an NTFS file partition called "Data", so I could manage files on both OSs and everything always worked just fine.

Now I bought a new Dell computer which came with Windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 16.10 right away, wishing the already existing (created on Windows) NTFS "Data" partition would also work on both systems like it always did on the older device.

I don't know if I did something wrong during the installation, because I can't do anything with any file or folder on this partition.

Here are all the issues I found, if it can help solving the problem:

a) "Data" partition mounts on boot but doesn't show on nautilus sidebar;

b) When I open it on nautilus via Dash, it says the owner is me but I can't create a folder, save a file, cut/copy/paste anything and so on;

c) When I open it via sudo, it says the owner is root but I can't change any permissions or manage files/folders either way;

d) chmod or chown won't work, I've already tried several times;

e) changing stuff on fstab won't work either, I've tried that too

I know there are several similar questions, but nothing I've found on this internet for about a month could help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you trying to mount your NTFS partition from the command line?

Comment: I tried from the command line, I tried on the Disks application, I tried editing fstab, everything I found and nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from Windows. Disable the **Fast startup** the open the windows terminal and run the following command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Boot from Ubuntu and run

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaX
```

Create a mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfs
```

Mount the NTFS partition:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdaX /mnt/ntfs
```

Replace `sdaX` with your NTFS partition.

Run :

```
gksu nautilus
```

Be careful because your about to run `nautilus` as root , change directory to `/mnt/ntfs`  to make changes.

Comment: Can't I mount this partition under /media? Would it make any difference?

Comment: Yes you can mount it under `/media`

Comment: 'nother question: when you say I should replace 'sdaX' with the NTFS partition, is it the UUID or sda5, for example?

Comment: replace `sdaX` with `sda5`

Comment: Ok thanks! Tried that but it shows the following output: Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: Remove the added entry from `fstab` reboot then try to mount your partition

Comment: I got the same output. Tried to unmount the partition but output says it's not mounted. Tried to unmount on nautilus and now I get the following: "The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.)" But Windows is shut down '-'

Comment: boot from windows disable the fast startup then run `powercfg /h off` as administrator , boot from ubuntu then run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5` and mount your partition

Comment: NOW it worked! *~throwing confetti~* but it still won't show on nautilus sidebar

Comment: Now try to create a new entry on your `fstab` file

Comment: Again? But why? And - would you help me, since the entry I created before was very different from the ones that were there previously, and I can't find the page that helped me doing that in the first place?